# Change Translation Controller Allowed PlaneType

Tags: android, arcore

I want to make some buttons that allow the user to select on which plane (X,Y,Z) his gesture can move my renderable.

Below is what I tried. It does actually change the "AllowedPlaneTypes" but the renderable cannot be moved. Do you have any idea why ? 
If I directly setup all the planes in setImage() the transformableNode is working for every plane.

```
public class AugmentedImageNode extends AnchorNode {
    private AugmentedImage image;
    private BaseArFragment arFragment;
    private TransformableNode node;

    public void setImage(AugmentedImage image) {
        Pose translation = image.getCenterPose().makeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        setAnchor(image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose().compose(translation)));

        this.node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.getScaleController().setEnabled(false);
        node.getTranslationController().setAllowedPlaneTypes(EnumSet.noneOf(Plane.Type.class));
        node.getRotationController().setEnabled(false);


        //Node node = new Node();
        node.setWorldScale(new Vector3(1,1,1));

        node.setParent(this);
        node.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(1f, 0, 0), 90f));
        node.setRenderable(x.getNow(null));

    }



  public void setTransformablePlaneTypes(String buttonId){
      EnumSet<Plane.Type> allowedPlaneTypes = EnumSet.allOf(Plane.Type.class);
      switch (buttonId){
          case "X" :
              allowedPlaneTypes = EnumSet.of(Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_DOWNWARD_FACING);
              this.node.getTranslationController().setAllowedPlaneTypes(allowedPlaneTypes);
              break;

          case "Y" :
              allowedPlaneTypes = EnumSet.of(Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING);
              this.node.getTranslationController().setAllowedPlaneTypes(allowedPlaneTypes);
              break;

          case "Z" :
              allowedPlaneTypes = EnumSet.of(Plane.Type.VERTICAL);
              this.node.getTranslationController().setAllowedPlaneTypes(allowedPlaneTypes);
              break;
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it possible that setting the `TransformableNode`'s parent to the `AugmentedImageNode` blocks the gesture from propagating down to the translation controller?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think so because if I activate the rotation controller it does actually rotate with gestures.

Comment: In what order are you calling `setImage` and `setTransformablePlaneTypes`?

Comment: "setImage" is called when the anchor is detected by arcore in the "onUpdateFrame" method. It also add on the screen the buttons that can trigger "setTransformablePlaneTypes" using the "onClick" method.